# What's the limitation of sexual consideration?

Tags: definition, prostitution

Prostitution is defined to be sex in exchange of consideration

http://definitions.uslegal.com/p/prostitution/

> The term "prostitution" generally means the commission by a person of
>   any natural or unnatural sexual act, deviate sexual intercourse, or
>   sexual contact for monetary consideration or other thing of value.

The problem is what sort of consideration count as prostitution?

Imagine a girl saying that I only want to have sex if we're married. That is a consideration. It has value. Is she a prostitute? Most of us wouldn't think so.

Imagine a girl saying, I only want to have sex if I get bitcoins. She's not getting paid. She's getting something else. Is she a prostitute?

So what's the limit?

What counts as consideration?

Comment: You do know what [consideration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consideration) _is_, right? Your examples aren't consideration.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a satisfying answer here. The real answer is that, yes, marriage is consideration and exchanging sex for marriage is prostitution, according to the definition provided. However, custom and tradition have carved out certain exceptions which society tolerates because society prefers it that way. Law - especially common law - isn't a formal mathematical proof where you can point at a line that's out of place and invalidate the whole thing. It's more like a high school English essay, with lots of notes scrawled in the margins. With coffee stains.

Comment: @jimsug - Bitcoin, a wedding, and a marriage contract all sound like "consideration" to me.  Can you explain your comment?

Comment: @feetwet (maybe I'm wrong) but consideration takes the form of a committment to do or not do something. Saying "I will only want to have sex if we're married" (note that marriage is not the same as a wedding) doesn't sound like an obligation. Maybe "I will have sex with you if we marry each other" could be. But _wanting_ to do something, afaik, is not consideration as it applies to contracts. A court can't force someone to want to do something, only to do it, and only if they've committed to doing so.

Comment: @jimsug - A traditional wedding alone can be a huge commitment of time and money, often demanded by one partner, and granted by the other for ... consideration.  The enforcement of the marriage contract has varied over time, but AFAIK it has always involved a commitment to do certain things and not do other things.  When the contract is liquidated by a divorce court usually some financial consideration is exacted from one of the parties.  As for the "physical" consideration, even if they aren't now, weren't "conjugal *rights*" a traditional part of the contract?

Comment: @feetwet I think you're conflating _marriage_ with _a wedding_ - marriage can occur without a wedding. The example stipulates marriage as a condition, not a wedding. Additionally, I've never heard of _wanting_ to do something being sufficient consideration. It would be like saying that "if you pay me $5 I will _want_ to give you this banana".

Comment: @feetwet additionally you're conflating the marriage contract with the supposed contract, which is _marriage_ in exchange for "want[ing] to have sex".

Comment: @jimsug - touche.  Looks like I was reading into this what I *thought* the OP was asking, instead of what he actually asked.  #LegalFail ;)

Comment: Actually marriage is an exception to exception. In general, explicit contract is prudent. But illegal for sex due to anti prostitution. However, marriage is an exception to the rule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the jurisdiction and particular facts.  The long history of not counting marriage as prostitution under law because of its social and religious legitimacy makes the transaction-related aspects of marriage fall outside the definition of prostitution in most cases that are not the explicit sale of a person for consideration, which is obviously forbidden as slavery today and could probably also be charged as prostitution in most jurisdictions.

In your particular example, the girl is also saying what things will influence how she feels, and no reasonable person would say that she gives up her ability to withhold consent after marriage based on any alleged contract.  A contract to lose the ability to withhold consent would also be void as against public policy, regardless of whether prostitution is involved.

Bitcoin is a form of virtual currency.  It is regulated by money transmitter law and trading it to obtain goods or services that cannot legally be traded for is still illegal.

It's not that there is a defined "limit."  It's that some things will fit into the definition and others won't.  It's about categories, not quantities.

Comment: I see. So the limit is not fixed. I give dollar and get sex. Bam. I give bitcoin and get sex. Bam. I give chocolate and get sex. Okay. I give financial support and get sex. Okay. Of course, while there is no explicit contract that I keep supporting as long as the sex keeps coming, we all know that I can find another partner if it stops.

Comment: There is no legally enforceable contract, implicit or explicit.  If you make an explicit agreement to trade consideration for sex, the contract is void and technically it is prostitution/solicitation.  Whether you find another partner or not--that is irrelevant to prostitution, although can be relevant to things like divorce in states that still have fault-based divorce laws.

Comment: so contract can't be explicit. The thing is the one sure way to get anything in this world, except by altruism is by having explicit "deals". And that is precisely what's prohibited

Comment: There is no contract for prostitution, explicit or implicit--the contract is void from the get-go.  "void ab initio."  This contract is not implicit or explicit.  It doesn't exist legally, at least not for purposes of trying to enforce it.

Comment: Yea but there are plenty of ways to enforce contract without resorting to laws. For example, there is an implicit contract that I would get a fair price if I go to wallmart because I would go somewhere else if I don't.

Comment: In fact, being an internet marketer I sort of have so many deals I never go to court with. No body is going to sue anybody.

Comment: Walmart: That's not a contract.  It's a consequence.

Comment: Yea. I see. Consequence. Which is all that truly matter in a contract,namely that both sides get positive consequences as agreed or expected. If she stops humping I stop supporting her. That too is not a contract. But consequences. Isn't that what people seek when they trade with others? They expect good consequences for themselves. Contract is just a way to create that consequences. Thanks for enlightening me on this one.

Comment: @TomW you are being parochial; prostitution is legal in many parts of the world and a contract for it in those jurisdictions would be valid.

Answer (score 3):

It rather begs the question of why it matters.

You are assuming that prostitution is illegal and therefore whether a transaction is or is not prostitution would be germane to this. However, in very many parts of the world prostitution is perfectly legal and may even be government regulated. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution_law

[image: Legality of Prostitution]

*Orange is illegal, green is legal, yellow is legal and government regulated*

Notwithstanding, whether legal, regulated or illegal, the definition of what prostitution is will be detailed in the law of the particular jurisdiction.

In jurisdictions where prostitution is legal, contracts for prostitution would be legally binding and while a prostitute (or the customer) could always withdraw consent because of sexual assault crimes that would be a breach of contract and would leave the party in breach subject to a damages claim.

Comment: This is also a good answer. The trick is that even when prostitution is legal it's treated worse than marriage. Prostitutes are taxed. While money given to spouses is not.

Comment: @jimThio That's not quite correct, what I give a prostitute is payment for services, what I give my spouse is a gift.

Comment: so gift is not taxed but payment is. Sounds like a loophole. Fuck me and I'll give you $100 as a gift.

Comment: Calling it a gift doesn't make it a gift

Comment: sometimes calling is the only things that make things is. For example, marriage is prostitution. We just don't call it that way.

Comment: @JimThio marriage doesn't necessarily involve sex. Sexual activity doesn't necessarily involve consideration or conditions. Some marriages may resemble prostitution. Others do not.

Comment: So a possibility that marriage doesn't necessarily involve sex, like escort, make it not a prostitution. Interesting.

Comment: Prostitution is legal in Indonesia by the way. Why my country is in orange?